# Problem in listing file names with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can get the list of files with specific extensions in python 2.7 with lower codes

```
import os

def discoverFiles(startpath):
    extensions = [
        'ext'
        ]

    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        for i in files:
            absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, i))
            ext = absolute_path.split('.')[-1]
            if ext in extensions:
                yield absolute_path

n_files = discoverFiles("D:\\") # DriveName For Search

for i in n_files:
    print(i)
```

But the code above does not work in Python 3
I need the code above
Please help me solve the problem in Python 3

Comment: Why doesn't the code work in Python 3?

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to run this in Python 3?

Comment: I do not know the reason

Comment: Seems to be working fine in `python3` (`linux`) for me. Not sure what is happening on windows

Comment: I do not get any error

Comment: `if onelist in otherlist` probably doesn't do what you hope. Try `any(x in extensions for x in ext)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

def discoverFiles(startpath):
    extensions = [
        'ext'
        ]

    F = os.listdir(startpath)

    for i in F:
        absolute_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(startpath, i))
        ext = absolute_path.split('.')[-1]
        if ext in extensions:
            yield (absolute_path)


n_files = discoverFiles("D:\\") # DriveName For Search

for i in n_files:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Tnx all for help ... :)